# Need for a Meta Post listing Authentic literature sources

Tags: discussion

Over my usage of the site i have noticed many users specifically asking for references to literature where some physical property is listed for a particular compound. Many a times i have also seen multiple sites giving different values for the same property of a particular substance.

I tried searching the meta for any such posts but couldn't find any, hence I am asking this question.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Should we allow data questions?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/135) As for the software, there is a [corresponding section](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37880/41328) in [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry) and also [Software to name compounds](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4066/41328).

Comment: @andselisk Got it I'll drop the software part however the literature part are a bit different. I'm asking for listing some reliable sources for the perusal of the users

Comment: I agree it would be nice to append a data-hoarding section with DBs and handbooks to [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry). As an intermediate cure note that there is [tag:databases] and [tag:reference-request] tags which, being combined with the area of interest in a search query, do pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @andselisk Ok Understood your point

Answer (score 7):

I'd say this is a duplicate of my previous request for such a canonical compilation: [“List of data sources” question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/list-of-data-sources-question?rq=1). But I think it may be a useful opportunity to reopen the discussion on this topic. **I stand by my opinion that it would be beneficial to have one such post.** It would also be a useful place to mention that values may not always agree with each other perfectly (due to experimental inaccuracies, etc.) which is something that many new (and experienced) chemists can forget.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Just read the answer to your linked query and thought: Why so negative? And then I saw my name. And then I was like: I don't know. And now I'm stuck in a loop, because on the one hand I understand myself, but on the other I know we need to try to know. I guess we just need to start it and hope for the best. **I second your opinion that it would be beneficial to have this post.**

Comment: @Martin-マーチン :D I saw your point back then and it is still a valid disclaimer. We can try, but it will probably never really be an exhaustive list. On the bright side, I think we do have a few users who are actually knowledgeable in this area. So we may get all the major sources in, at least.